# Connect non-local neo4j server via .NET driver

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, database-connection

I want to connect to a remote neo4J server via the .NET driver.

Currently I get the

> Neo4j.Driver.V1.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection with the server breaks due to AggregateException:
>   (The rest of the Exception is in german, but it translates to:)
>   No connection could be established, because the goal-computer refused the connection to  127.0.0.1:7687

and I fail to fix the error.

## My code:

```
Config conf = new Config { EncryptionLevel = EncryptionLevel.None };
            using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://Server-IP:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo4j"), conf))

            using (var session = driver.Session()) {
                var result = session.Run("MATCH (a:Model)  RETURN a");
            }
```

## Neo4J Settings:

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.

# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:

dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

I changed this line, everything else is untouched.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you restart Neo4j after making the change to neo4j.conf ?
2. Does a netstat -an on the Neo4j server show that ports 7474 and 7687 are
   listening on 0.0.0.0 (and not on 127.0.0.1)
3. Does a nmap -p 7474 Server-ip from your client show that the port is
   OPEN (CLOSED or FILTERED indicate a firewall)
4. Idem but for port 7687

If all those check out it should work ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: 1.) Yes I did that.
2.) Yes they are listed. (0.0.0.0:7474 and 7687)

Comment: 3.) and 4.) are both return as "open"...

What else can I check? (still does not work)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now the communication works!